# Determining if a grid is solvable

Tags: python, recursion

I'm making a simple "Rumba Robot" simulation. I've included the whole code below, though I'm only asking about the is_furniture_valid function. There are green tiles that are furniture that the vacuum must clean around. The vacuum checks its next location every step. If that location is invalid, it picks a random new direction. Grids are made randomly and then checked to see if they are valid.

My is_furniture_valid function ensures that the grid is solvable. For example, this grid ([invalid grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ALLF.png)) is invalid because the vacuum cannot access all the tiles.

Everything works how I want it to; however, since the is_furniture_valid function calls the recursive find_accessable_tiles function, it only works for grids less than about 50 x 50 before it reaches the maximum recursive depth. How else can I define a non-recursive function that ensures that a grid is solvable?

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Robot Vacuum Cleaner """

import Tkinter as tk 
import random

#### METHODS ####

def scale_vector(vector, velocity):
    """
    Create unit vector. Multiply each component of unit vector
    by the magnitude of the desired vector (velocity).
    """
    try:
        x = float(vector[0])/((vector[0]**2+vector[1]**2)**.5)
        y = float(vector[1])/((vector[0]**2+vector[1]**2)**.5)
        return int(x*velocity), int(y*velocity)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return None, None

def get_random_velocity(velocity):
    """
    Create random direction vector.
    Scale direction vector with scale_vector method.
    """
    vx, vy = None, None
    while vx == None and vy == None:
        vector = (random.random()*random.choice([-1, 1]),
                 random.random()*random.choice([-1, 1]))
        vx, vy = scale_vector(vector, velocity)
    return vx, vy

def make_grid(furniture, dimension):
    """
    Scale actual (x, y) positions down to a grid (dictionary) 
    with keys (Nx*1, Ny*1) where Nx and Ny range from 1 to dimension[0] 
    and 1 to dimension[1] respectively.
    The keys are mapped to a boolean indicating whether that tile
    is occupied with furniture (True) or not (False).
    furniture: list with pixle locations. Each element ~ (x, y, x+dx, y+dy).
    dimension: tuple, x by y dimensions (x, y).
    returns: grid = {(1, 1): False, (2, 1): True, ...}
    """
    #dx, dy are width and height of tiles.
    dx = furniture[0][2] - furniture[0][0]
    dy = furniture[0][3] - furniture[0][1]
    w, h = dx*dimension[0], dy*dimension[1]

    grid = {}
    for y in xrange(1, dimension[1]+1):
        for x in xrange(1, dimension[0]+1):
            grid[(x, y)] = False

    y_grid = 0
    for y in xrange(dy/2, h, dy):
        y_grid += 1
        x_grid = 0
        for x in xrange(dx/2, w, dx):
            x_grid += 1
            for element in furniture:
                if x >= element[0] and x <= element[2] \
                and y >= element[1] and y <= element[3]:
                    grid[(x_grid, y_grid)] = True
                    break
    return grid

def find_accessable_tiles(grid, position, l=[]):
    """
    Finds all non-furniture locations that are accessable
    when starting at position 'position'.
    *** Mutates l ***
    Assumes position is not at a point such that grid[position] == True.
    In other words, the initial positions is valid and is not occupied.
    grid: dict mapping a Grid to booleans (tiles with/without furniture).
        i.e. grid = {(1, 1): False, (2, 1): True, ...}
    position: tuple (x, y)
    l: list
    """
    l.append(position)
    x, y = position
    if (x+1, y) in grid and (x+1, y) not in l and not grid[(x+1, y)]: #right
        find_accessable_tiles(grid, (x+1, y), l)
    if (x-1, y) in grid and (x-1, y) not in l and not grid[(x-1, y)]: #left
        find_accessable_tiles(grid, (x-1, y), l)
    if (x, y+1) in grid and (x, y+1) not in l and not grid[(x, y+1)]: #down
        find_accessable_tiles(grid, (x, y+1), l)
    if (x, y-1) in grid and (x, y-1) not in l and not grid[(x, y-1)]: #up
        find_accessable_tiles(grid, (x, y-1), l)
    return l

def is_furniture_valid(furniture, dimension):
    """
    Checks to see if all non-furniture tiles can be accessed
    when starting initially at position (1, 1).
    furniture: list of (x, y, x+dx, y+dy).
    dimension: tuple, x by y dimensions (x, y).
    """
    if len(furniture) == 0: #Rooms with no furniture are valid.
        return True
    grid = make_grid(furniture, dimension)
    #Start position is (1, 1).
    accessable_tiles = find_accessable_tiles(grid, (1, 1), [])
    #Compare accessable tiles to all non-furniture tiles.
    for element in grid:
        #if a tile doesn't have furniture AND is not accessible,
        #room is not valid.
        if not grid[element] and element not in accessable_tiles:
            return False
    return True

#### OBJECT DEFINITIONS ####

class Rumba(object):
    """
    Dealing with the actual Rumba robot on the screen - red square.
    canvas: tk.Canvas object.
    position: tuple (x, y).
    width: int width of square.
    """
    def __init__(self, canvas, position, width):       
        self.can, self.width = canvas, width  
        self.Draw(position)

    def Draw(self, position):
        x, y = position
        x1, y1 = x + self.width, y + self.width
        x2, y2 = x + self.width, y - self.width
        x3, y3 = x - self.width, y - self.width
        x4, y4 = x - self.width, y + self.width

        self.vacuum = self.can.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, fill="red")
        self.line1 = self.can.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black")
        self.line2 = self.can.create_line(x2, y2, x3, y3, fill="black")
        self.line3 = self.can.create_line(x3, y3, x4, y4, fill="black")
        self.line4 = self.can.create_line(x1, y1, x4, y4, fill="black")

    def update_position(self, new_position):
        x, y = new_position       
        x1, y1 = x + self.width, y + self.width
        x2, y2 = x + self.width, y - self.width
        x3, y3 = x - self.width, y - self.width
        x4, y4 = x - self.width, y + self.width

        self.can.coords(self.vacuum, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)
        self.can.coords(self.line1, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        self.can.coords(self.line2, x2, y2, x3, y3)
        self.can.coords(self.line3, x3, y3, x4, y4)
        self.can.coords(self.line4, x1, y1, x4, y4)

class Grid(object):
    """
    The grid that the vacuum will clean.
    canvas: tk.Canvas object.
    dimension: tuple of number of tiles (x, y).
    screen: tuple of size of canvas (w, h).
    furniture: boolean - if room will have furniture.
    """
    def __init__(self, canvas, dimension, screen, furniture=True):
        self.can, self.dimension = canvas, dimension
        self.w, self.h = screen

        self.create_tiles(furniture)

    def create_tiles(self, furniture):
        """
        Finds a valid configuration of furniture and tiles.
        Then, calls self.draw_tiles to draw configuration.
        """
        #dx, dy are width and height of tiles.
        dx, dy = self.w//self.dimension[0], self.h//self.dimension[1]

        #adjust screen size for discrepincies in forcing int divition.
        self.w, self.h = self.dimension[0]*dx, self.dimension[1]*dy
        self.can.config(width=self.w, height=self.h)

        valid = False
        while not valid:
            tiles, furniture_tiles = [], []
            for y in xrange(0, self.h, dy):
                for x in xrange(0, self.w, dx):
                    #(0, 0) is always a non-furniture tile.
                    if not furniture or random.random() <= 0.8 or (x, y) == (0, 0):                    
                        tiles.append((x, y, x+dx, y+dy))
                    else:
                        furniture_tiles.append((x, y, x+dx, y+dy))
            valid = is_furniture_valid(furniture_tiles, self.dimension)

        self.draw_tiles(tiles, furniture_tiles)

    def draw_tiles(self, tiles, furniture_tiles):
        """
        Draws a configuration of furniture and tiles.
        tiles: list of position tuples, (x, y, x+dx, y+dy).
        furniture_tiles: same as tiles but only for furniture.
        """
        self.furniture = furniture_tiles
        for element in self.furniture:
            x, y = element[0], element[1]
            dx, dy = element[2] - x, element[3] - y
            self.can.create_rectangle(x, y, x+dx, y+dy, fill="green")

        self.tiles = {}
        for element in tiles:
            x, y = element[0], element[1]
            dx, dy = element[2] - x, element[3] - y
            self.tiles[element] = [4,  
                    self.can.create_rectangle(x, y, x+dx, y+dy, fill="black")]

    def get_tile(self, position):
        x, y = position
        for element in self.tiles:
            if x >= element[0] and x <= element[2] \
            and y >= element[1] and y <= element[3]:
                return element

    def clean_tile(self, position):
        """
        Takes 4 times to clean a tile.
        Usually, vacuum will clean 2 at a time though.
        *** On some screens, 'dark grey' is lighter than 'grey'. ***
        """
        tile = self.get_tile(position)
        self.tiles[tile][0] -= 1
        if self.tiles[tile][0] == 0:
            self.can.itemconfig(self.tiles[tile][1], fill="white")
        elif self.tiles[tile][0] == 1:
            self.can.itemconfig(self.tiles[tile][1], fill="light grey")
        elif self.tiles[tile][0] == 2:
            self.can.itemconfig(self.tiles[tile][1], fill="grey")
        elif self.tiles[tile][0] == 3:
            self.can.itemconfig(self.tiles[tile][1], fill="dark grey")

    def is_grid_cleaned(self):
        for element in self.tiles.itervalues():
            if element[0] > 0:
                return False
        return True

    def get_dimension(self):
        return self.dimension
    def get_grid_size(self):
        return (self.w, self.h)
    def get_furniture(self):
        return self.furniture

class Robot(object):
    """
    Completes the numerical simulation.
    grid: a Grid object.
    canvas: a tk.Canvas object.
    v: int speed of robot.
    """
    def __init__(self, grid, canvas, v):
        self.grid = grid
        self.w, self.h = self.grid.get_grid_size()
        self.furniture = self.grid.get_furniture()

        self.v = v
        self.set_random_velocity()

        average_size = sum(self.grid.get_grid_size())/2
        average_dimension = sum(self.grid.get_dimension())/2
        self.robot_width = int((average_size/average_dimension)*0.3)
        #initial position
        self.x, self.y = self.robot_width, self.robot_width

        self.rumba = Rumba(canvas, (self.x, self.y), self.robot_width)

    def is_valid_position(self, position):
        x, y = position
        if x + self.robot_width >= self.w or x - self.robot_width <= 0:
            return False
        elif y + self.robot_width >= self.h or y - self.robot_width <= 0:
            return False
        for element in self.furniture:
            #element is of the form (x, y, x+dx, y+dy)
            if x >= element[0] and x <= element[2]:
                if y >= element[1] and y <= element[3]:
                    return False
                elif y + self.robot_width >= element[1] and y + self.robot_width <= element[3]:
                    return False
                elif y - self.robot_width >= element[1] and y - self.robot_width <= element[3]:
                    return False
            elif x + self.robot_width >= element[0] and x + self.robot_width <= element[2]:
                if y >= element[1] and y <= element[3]:
                    return False
                elif y + self.robot_width >= element[1] and y + self.robot_width <= element[3]:
                    return False
                elif y - self.robot_width >= element[1] and y - self.robot_width <= element[3]:
                    return False
            elif x - self.robot_width >= element[0] and x - self.robot_width <= element[2]:
                if y >= element[1] and y <= element[3]:
                    return False
                elif y + self.robot_width >= element[1] and y + self.robot_width <= element[3]:
                    return False
                elif y - self.robot_width >= element[1] and y - self.robot_width <= element[3]:
                    return False       
        return True

    def set_random_velocity(self):
        self.vx, self.vy = get_random_velocity(self.v)

    def update(self):
        """
        Checks to see if current direction is valid.
        If it is, continues, if not, picks new,
        random directions until it finds a valid direction.
        """
        x, y = self.x+self.vx, self.y+self.vy
        while (x, y) == (self.x, self.y) or not self.is_valid_position((x, y)):
            self.set_random_velocity()
            x, y = self.x+self.vx, self.y+self.vy
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.rumba.update_position((self.x, self.y))
        self.grid.clean_tile((self.x, self.y))

#### OBJECTS MANAGER ####

class Home(object):
    """
    Manages Simulation.
    master: tk.Tk object.
    screen: tuple (width, height).
    dimension: tuple, dimension of the grid.
    """
    def __init__(self, master, screen, dimension):
        master.title("Rumba Robot")
        master.resizable(0, 0)
        try:
            master.wm_iconbitmap("ploticon.ico")
        except:
            pass
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        v = sum(screen)//(2*sum(dimension))

        canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=screen[0], height=screen[1])
        canvas.pack()
        grid = Grid(canvas, dimension, screen)
        robot = Robot(grid, canvas, v)

        master.bind('<Return>', self.restart)
        master.bind('<Up>', self.fast)
        master.bind('<Down>', self.slow)

        #initialize class variables.
        self.master, self.frame = master, frame
        self.screen, self.dimension = screen, dimension
        self.robot, self.grid = robot, grid

        #self.speed adjusts frame rate. Can be manipulated with arrow keys.
        #self.count keeps track of steps.
        self.speed, self.count = 100, 0

        self.update()

    def restart(self, callback=False):
        """ Enter/Return Key """
        self.frame.destroy()
        self.__init__(self.master, self.screen, self.dimension)

    def fast(self, callback=False):
        """ Up arrow key """
        if self.speed > 5:
            self.speed -= 5
        else:
            self.speed = 1

    def slow(self, callback=False):
        """ Down arrow key """
        self.speed += 5

    def update(self):
        self.robot.update()
        self.count += 1
        self.master.title("Rumba Robot - Steps: %d" % self.count)

        if not self.grid.is_grid_cleaned():
            self.frame.after(self.speed, self.update)
        else:
            self.frame.bell()

#### SIMULATION ####

def simulate(screen, dimension):
    """ 
    screen and dimension: both tuples.
    """
    root = tk.Tk()
    Home(root, screen, dimension)
    #Center window on screen.
    root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Maximum dimension ~~ between (45, 45) - (50, 50) due to
    maximum recursion depth for find_accessable_tiles function.

    *** Large dimensions may take a few seconds to generate ***

    Tip: Up/Down arrow keys will speed/slow the simulation.
    Enter/Return will restart with the same screen and dimension attributes.
    """
    screen = 1000, 700
    dimension = 30, 20

    simulate(screen, dimension)
```

It's pretty fun to watch too, haha. Use up/down arrow keys to speed/slow the simulation.

Comment: Generally it's preferred if you can present your question in the form of a [mcve] that focuses on your problem, rather than posting 400+ lines of code. But I must admit that it _is_ fun to watch the Roomba do its thing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-recursive version of `find_accessable_tiles`.

Rather than recursing, it pushes the tiles to be tested onto the end of a queue, implemented as a list named `tile_queue`. I've replaced your `l` with a set named `accessable` because testing set membership is more efficient than testing list membership; also sets can't have duplicate members, but we aren't really utilizing that property here. Because we're not recursing we don't pass `accessable` into `find_accessable_tiles` as an argument, but of course we *do* need to return it.

In the loop, the position of the current tile is popped from the front of the queue, the 4 neighbors of this current tile are calculated and tested, if a neighbor is valid it's added both to the `accessable` set and to `tile_queue`.

This code seems to work ok, but it does get slow when the room dimensions are large, partly because there are simply more tiles to test, but also because there's more scope for inaccessible regions to be formed. So you may need to come up with a less random strategy for laying out the "furniture" so that you don't need to do this test.

FWIW, it's a good idea when developing programs that use random numbers to seed the random number generator so you can  test modified version of the various algorithms on the same data.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
deltas = ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1))

def neighbor(position, delta):
    return position[0] + delta[0], position[1] + delta[1]

def find_accessable_tiles_NEW(grid, position):
    accessable = set()
    accessable.add(position)
    tile_queue = [position]
    while tile_queue:
        current = tile_queue.pop(0)
        for position in [neighbor(current, d) for d in deltas]:
            if position in grid and not grid[position] and position not in accessable:
                accessable.add(position)
                tile_queue.append(position)

    return accessable
```

---

For testing purpose, I found it useful to add some `print` calls to `create_tiles`. We print a dot for each room arrangement that's tested so we know the program's actually doing something. :)

```
while not valid:
    print('.', end='', file=sys.stderr)
    tiles, furniture_tiles = [], []
    for y in xrange(0, self.h, dy):
        for x in xrange(0, self.w, dx):
            #(0, 0) is always a non-furniture tile.
            if not furniture or random.random() <= 0.8 or (x, y) == (0, 0):                    
                tiles.append((x, y, x+dx, y+dy))
            else:
                furniture_tiles.append((x, y, x+dx, y+dy))
    valid = is_furniture_valid(furniture_tiles, self.dimension)

print(file=sys.stderr)
```

Don't forget to put

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of your script to make the `print` function available in Python 2.

---

As augurar mentions in the comment, using a simple list as a queue isn't very efficient: when you pop an element from the front of the queue all the other elements have to be moved down. True, that operation happens at C speed, so it's faster than doing it with a Python loop, but it's still a good idea to avoid that, especially when the queue can be large, like it is here.

Fortunately, the standard Python library provides a queue object called a deque, in the `collections` module. Here's `find_accessable_tiles_NEW` using a `deque`.

```
from collections import deque

def find_accessable_tiles_NEW(grid, position):
    accessable = set()
    accessable.add(position)
    tile_queue = deque()
    tile_queue.append(position)
    while tile_queue:
        current = tile_queue.popleft()
        for position in [neighbor(current, d) for d in deltas]:
            if position in grid and not grid[position] and position not in accessable:
                accessable.add(position)
                tile_queue.append(position)

    return accessable
```

I just did a speed test comparison; the `deque` version found a valid grid in about 2/3 of the time of my original `list`-based version with the same random number seed. Of course, the actual speed difference will vary depending on the random number seed and the room dimensions, but the `deque` version will be consistently faster.

Comment: Removing the first element of a list is an `O(n)` operation.  Use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead.

Comment: @augurar: Good point; I guess it may speed things up here, since the queue does get rather large.

Comment: @augurar: Fixed. I really should've used a deque in the first place... :)

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for - a very simple but effective solution! I changed the neighbor function to a generator that yields all four neighboring tiles. Would that be faster than the way you did it, or are generators usually slower? I'd imagine, in this case anyway, there is not much of a difference.

Comment: @Joe No worries. :) There probably won't be much speed difference getting the neighbors with a generator function, you'd really have to do `timeit` tests to find out. However, a generator _expression_ tends to be slightly slower than the equivalent list comprehension, both in setup time & running time, although that difference is reduced a bit in Python 3 because list comps in Py 3 create a new scope rather than running in the scope of the surrounding code; generators always create a new scope.